# JQuery, Create multiple html Element with ascending IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is what is needed to do:

```html
<input type="text" id="main" placeholder="Put URL Here">
```

Every time the User Presses enter (or a Button on side of screen) I need Jquery to create:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="url_1" readonly value='<-- input value from main-->'>
<!-- user adds another to #main -->
<input type="hidden" id="url_2" readonly value='<-- input value from main-->'>
<!-- etc -->
```

Here is what I got So far (only using HTML)

```html
<figure class="mb-4">
<input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Image URL">
<button id="addimage">Add Image</button>
<button id="uploadimage_js">Upload Image</button>
</figure>
```

For the Upload Image button, It submits a Image to my PHP upload image, and just returns the URL to the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will append the hidden inputs to the end of your `<form>` tag. It also keeps an array of urls in case that's useful. For this snippet, it shows the array in a div.

```js
let urls = [], limit = 2, main, addButton, resetButton
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  main = document.querySelector('#main'),
  addButton = document.querySelector('[data-url-saver]'),
  resetButton = document.querySelector('[data-url-reset]');
  addButton.addEventListener('click', () => saveURL())
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => reset())
  })

const saveURL = () => {
  let u = main.value;
  urls.push(u);
  let h = `<input type="hidden" data-url-hidden id="url_${urls.length}" readonly value=${u} />`
  document.querySelector('form').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', h);
  main.value = "";
  let de = document.querySelector('#debug');
  de.innerHTML = urls.join(", ");
  if (urls.length >= limit) {
    addButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    main.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    main.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Maximum URLs accepted')
  }
}

const reset = () => {
  urls = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-url-hidden]').forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
  addButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  main.removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.querySelector('#debug').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="main" placeholder="Put URL Here">
  <button data-url-saver type='button'>enter</button>
  <button data-url-reset type='button'>reset</button>
</form>

<div id='debug'></div>
```

Comment: this is the exact way I wanted it thank you, I do have a Question, is there a way to Limit How many times it Can be Run? (I only run it to be able to run lets say 20 times then stop the user from putting moree)

Comment: ok, its updated with a `limit` variable. It's set to 2 in the snippet so you can test it. Cheers

Comment: sorry, slightly got overwhelmed, Yours is the correct answer, sorry and thank you

Comment: @NolanO, out of interest, why mark this as the correct answer when you specified jQuery code (I've nothing against this answer, I'm just curious).

Comment: @Kinglish, you might want to think about caching `document.querySelector('#main')` in a variable. It'll make your code shorter/neater.

Comment: Jquery isnt Needed Per say, just Easier (as i dont know Plain Javascript too well, just know jquery) But I can understand How you did it.

Comment: @Kinglish by chance, is there a Way to reset the form? (lets say a User added the wrong item?)

Comment: @NolanO - sure, would that remove all urls and start at the beginning? how would you want that to trigger. A reset button?

Comment: Just like that, Clear all URLS, like a Reset button (or if even possible, Remove "last" url entered, but that is alot to ask)

Comment: Ok, updated with a reset button and @Andy 's excellent code reducing suggestion. Note that I wrapped the button event listeners in a window.load listener to make sure the page has had a chance to render before those kick in.

Answer (score 2):

Create a div for hidden urls like

```
<div id="urls"></div>
```

try in jquery

```
var counter = 1;
$('#main').keypress(function (e) {
 if(e.which== 13){  // enter key code
    var url = $('#main').val();
    $('#urls').append('<input type="hidden" id="url_'+ counter +'" readonly value="' + url + '" >');
    $('#main').val(''); //clearing the input
    counter++;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add ascending URL and if you have the link, then you can use the function below.

```js
function addImage(){
  var link = document.querySelector('#main').value;
  var all_links = document.getElementById('all_urls');
  if (link.length > 0){
    code = `
    <input type="hidden" id="url_${all_links.children.length}" value="${link}"/>
    `
    all_links.innerHTML += code;
    console.log(document.getElementById('all_urls'))
  }
}
```

```html
<figure class="mb-4">
<input type="text" id="main" placeholder="Put URL Here">
<div id="all_urls">
<!--All the links are added here-->
</div>
<button id="addimage" onclick="addImage()">Add Image</button>
<button id="uploadimage_js">Upload Image</button>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery

```js
// Cache some elements
const div = $('div');
const main = $('#main');

$('button').click(() => {

 // Grab the value
 const val = main.val();

 // Create the id based on the current
 // number of inputs 
 const id = div.find('input').length + 1;

 // Append the new input
 div.append(`<input readonly id="url_${id}" value="${val}" />`);

 // Reset the main input 
 main.val('');

});
```

```css
div { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="main" />
<button>Click</button>
<div></div>
```

And the equivalent in vanilla JS:

```js
// Cache some elements
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false)

function handleClick() {

 // Create the id based on the current
 // number of inputs 
 const id = div.querySelectorAll('input').length + 1;

  const html = `<input readonly id="url_${id}" value="${main.value}" />`;

 // Append the new input
 div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

 // Reset the main input 
 main.value = '';

};
```

```css
div { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="main" />
<button>Click</button>
<div></div>
```